# SPNEGO: Server receiving a truncated token than the one client is sending

Tags: kerberos, solrcloud, spnego

I am trying to interact with a SolrCloud cluster with Kerberos enabled. I have configured my client java process with `jaas.conf` and `krb5.conf` files using the options

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path to jaas.conf>
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=<path to krb5.conf>
```

I receive a forbidden error in client logs. Server logs show the following error:

> Authentication exception: GSSException: Defective token detected
>   (Mechanism level: Invalid SPNEGO NegTokenInit token : extra data given
>   to DerValue constructor)

On enabling debug logging in the client and server process, I see that the server is receiving a smaller token than what the client is sending.
Example:

```
Found KeyTab solr.keytab for HTTP/<hostname>@REALM
Found KeyTab solr.keytab for HTTP/<hostname>@REALM
Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = a0 82 04 b9 30 82 04 b5 a0 0d 30 0b 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 a1 04 03 02 01 f6 a2 82 04 9c 04 82 04 98 60 82 04 94 06 09 2a 86 
Found KeyTab solr.keytab for HTTP/<hostname>@REALM
Found KeyTab solr.keytab for HTTP/<hostname>@REALM
Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = a0 82 04 b9 30 82 04 b5 a0 0d 30 0b 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 a1 04 03 02 01 f6 a2 82 04 9c 04 82 04 98 60 82 04 94 06 09 2a 86
```

The client is sending a much longer token. I verified this by client debug logs where the sending token is much longer and by also looking at the HTTP request header.

By looking at the source code, I see that the error is caused by the following lines:
https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/util/DerValue.java#L383
https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/jgss/spnego/NegTokenInit.java#L143
https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/jgss/spnego/SpNegoContext.java#L512

The same SOLR nodes that I am trying to connect programmatically are accessible via the browser and server logs show that they receive the full token.
I am using Java 1.8.0_111 and also tried Java 1.8.0_11

Comment: Increase your header buffer size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a TCP dump and looking at the request that was being sent from the client, I found out that the underlying HTTP client library was truncating the base64 encoded Kerberos token to 76 characters per line and then adding CRLF characters. More info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018148/commons-http-client-kerberos-token-while-negotiating-has-r-n-carriage-return) answer. Using a newer version of commons-codec, which was used by Apache HttpClient library) fixed it.